# Connectedness of exceptional divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, singularity-theory, blowup

Let $X$ be a quasi-projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $I$ be an ideal sheaf supported at a closed point on $X$. Is the exceptional divisor for the blow-up of $X$ along the ideal sheaf $I$, connected? Any reference will be most welcome.

Comment: No. The blowup of a nodal curve at the node is the same as its normalization, meaning that the exceptional divisor consists of two isolated points.

Comment: @TabesBridges this looks like an answer to me! Would you care to record it as such below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider the blowup of a nodal curve at the node. This is the same as the normalization, so the exceptional divisor is just the two isolated points lying over the node.